# ondblclick myfunction() does not fire

Tags: javascript

I have the following html code which does not seem to trigger the function toggle().

```
<div id="element" align="center" ondblclick="toggle()" >
  <h1>
  <p id="tennis">
B
  </p>

</h1>
  <p id="date">
  </p>

</div>
```

The javascript function is below and can be exercised [at fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zerowords/sqtqtkxb/).

```
function toggle() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

Am I accessing the function incorrectly, or what?

Comment: Change the load type option in your jsFiddle. By default it wraps your code within a `window.onload` function

Comment: And use your JavaScript console (F12) to see the errors. You'll still have some once you do that ↑.

Comment: Remove `onclick` from here. `<div id="element" align="center" ondblclick="toggle()" onclick='alert( "HHII")'>`

Comment: Using chrome on Mac. j08691, which option do you mean. Under settings I don't see a load type option. blex, F12 does not do anything on my Mac in jsfiddle. Is there some automatic way to put the fiddle code into it's own standalone html document where I am more familiar with seeing javascript console.

Comment: Also, `el = (el = 'B' ? 'B' : 'K');` should be `document.getElementById("tennis").innerHTML = (el == 'B' ? 'B' : 'K');`

Comment: Both Shreevardhan and Johnny Mopp are commenting on changes that I have made earlier at jsFiddle. So I must not be updating or saving correctly. I think that update /7/ is current, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the JS load type.

Javascript:

```
function toggle() {
  // alert("hi");
  var el = document.getElementById("tennis").innerHTML;
  el = (el === 'B' ? 'K' : 'B');
  document.getElementById("tennis").innerHTML = el;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="element" align="center" ondblclick="toggle()">
  <h1>
    <p id="tennis">B</p>
  </h1>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqtqtkxb/6/)

Comment: Yes, this works nicely. What did you mean or how did you do "Change the JS load type?"

Comment: In JS Fiddle, click the "JAVASCRIPT" button on top right of Javascript section. You can change the "LOAD TYPE" here. It is set to "OnLoad" by default.

Comment: Yes, I found that by clicking on Javascript settings/preferences you change the JS load type. I changed it to "No wrap - in <body>" and that works even better for me than does your selection: "No wrap - in <head>" .    Earlier I only saw "Settings" at the top right of the page.